# Modify an element with Primefaces collector

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces collector and it works perfect to add or remove an element from a backing bean, but I don´t know how can I modify an element of that collection because the collector tag only has the add and remove attributes.

Which is the best approach to do this?

I'm thinking in use a commandButton and pass the object as a parameter and then modify it in a dialog, but I'm not sure. Has someone have done this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this will depend on your design.

What you mentioned is doable and I also have done it in some of my projects. But as an added suggestion, primefaces `datatable` has an edit function. see [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) This allows you to edit your data on the table itself.